# NSPredicate iphone coredata search

Tags: iphone, search, core-data

I have a table populated with coredata (all staff), but I need another table with only staff from one center (there are 3 centers),

the center is an attribute in my entity,

so how can I show this list? (populate table with staff from x center?) do I use NSPredicate?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you a function which returns you array according to center type what you need to a column called center in your entity.

and in folloeing function you need to pass center name like @"x" or @"y".And function give you what you want.

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)getRecordsByCenter:(NSString *)cen{
        NSMutableArray *fetchResults;

        NSString *entityName=@"YourEntity";
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:globalManagedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        fetchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[globalManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]];

    [fetchResults filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"center == %@",cen]] ;
        [fetchRequest release];

        return fetchResults;

    }
```